# SQL Injection in SQL Dynamic SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPC_COMMON_LST1
    @P_tables       nvarchar(max)   =   '',
    @P_columns      nvarchar(max)   =   '*',
    @P_conditions   nvarchar(max)   =   '(1 = 1)'
AS
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @P_columns + ' FROM ' + @P_tables + ' WHERE     @P_conditions '

    SET @params = N' @P_conditions NVARCHAR(500)  ';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @P_conditions 
END
```

In `where` condition I don't want have attack by SQL injection.

By when I run the stored procedure

```
EXECUTE SPC_COMMON_LST1 'M610','client_cd, client_nm','(client_cd = 0000010001) AND (del_flag = 0)'
```

I get an error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@P_conditions'

Comment: What you're trying to do simply isn't possible. In the first place, if they can enter dynamic SQL at `@P_conditions` then presumably they can also enter it for `@P_columns` and `@P_tables`. But ignoring that, you can't really use parameters for what you're doing. What you should be doing if you want to do something like this is thinking of smart ways to sanitise the input before it even reaches the procedure.

Comment: IMO you can use `' WHERE (' + @P_Conditions + ') OR (1 = 0)'` as a trick - Commented for votes ;).

Comment: Or use `' WHERE CASE WHEN ' + @P_Conditions + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1'` - Commented for votes ;).